# pandas to_csv() fails to save the results

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using Pandas for creating a data frame that reads values from a comma separated file initially. The CSV file contains a dataset related to the employees. The data from the csv file is normalized between the range of 0-1 using MinMaxScaler. The normalization step works fine and the print statement prints out the normalizaed results of the attributes. But when I try to save these results (normalized values) against each attribute in a new CSV file, it creates a new file "Employees_modified" with the same values as that of the "Employees" dataset that were given as input to the MinMaxScaler function. I am new to Pandas and couldn't figure out where possibly is the mistake.
My code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
dframe = pd.read_csv('Employees.csv')
one_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
one_scaler.partial_fit(dframe)
a_scaled = one_scaler.transform(dframe)
print(a_scaled)
dframe.to_csv('Employees_modified.csv')
```

I want to save normalized values in my Employees_modified file but the results are being lost somewhere in between.

Comment: What do you mean it's lost? Do you get any output file at all? What's in it and what do you expect to be in it?

Comment: you're saving the original dataframe, not the result of the transformation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing the original dataframe to the file.
The code below should do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
dframe = pd.read_csv('Employees.csv')
one_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
one_scaler.partial_fit(dframe)
a_scaled = one_scaler.transform(dframe)
print(a_scaled)
#creates a dataframe from the scaled data
pd.DataFrame(a_scaled, columns=list(dframe)).to_csv('Employees_modified.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
one_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy=False)
```

Comment: thank you for providing an answer. Please provide more information as to how the changes you've proposed in your answer will help to fix the issue in question.

Comment: Try to run the same code just changing the line I pointed out. By default, MinMaxScaler operates on a copy of your dataFrame. So when you print your original dataframe nothing changed. The argument 'copy=False' tells the scaler to not copy, but operate over your original dataframe. I hope it helps.

Comment: @AResem I appreciate your contribution but your proposed solution didn't make any change to my Employee_modified file